# JavaScript: Unexpected Inheritance Result

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and I'm going through tutorials to familiarize myself. I keep getting 12 for the name, but I feel like it should be the default name (since it was never updated). It's pretty basic, but I can't find the error. Also, I'm sure that I'm using function wrong in the require, but I wasn't exactly sure how else to do it.

I should note that Person.js is on a server way out there, while PersonEmployee.html is local.

PersonEmployee.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
        <title>Dojo Check</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>

    require(["http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~wtaylor/Sandbox/Inheritance2/Person.js"], function(){
            var aPerson = new Person("Tommy", 12, "Da Hood");
        var emp = new Employee(12);
        alert(emp.name);
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Person.js:

```
dojo.declare("Person", null,{
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 0,
    address: "",
    constructor: function(name, age, address) {
        this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
    }
});

dojo.declare("Employee", Person, {
    id : 0,
    constructor: function(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the employee

Comment: Whoops! Just saw that I failed to do so-- updated :)

Comment: What tutorials are you reading? You have a really funky mix of old and new code going on here.

Answer (score 1):

> A good practice for constructors is to avoid modifications of its
>   arguments. It ensures that other classes can access original values,
>   and allows to play nice when the class is used as a building block for
>   other classes.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#default-constructor-chaining

Both constructors are being called with only one parameter (12).  When person is called, 12 is passed as the name parameter.

---

RESPONSE TO COMMENT

Instead of passing an argument list, pass a single object argument and in the constructor of the top most object mixin the parameter object:

```
var Person = dojo.declare("Person", null,{     
    constructor: function(params) {
        if(params)
            dojo.mixin(this, params);
    }
});

var Employee = dojo.declare("Employee", Person, {
    id : 0
});

var emp = new Employee({
    id: 12
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-mixin

Comment: I'm a very object oriented person (was big on Java). I was more interested in having a separate .js class that defined Emp/Person, and having the .html call on that. Is there a way to do that (much like what I originally had, but through chaining in a separate .js file).

Comment: Updated my answer to give an example